# Can I open a report based on record selected on a form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I looking for an VBA solution (in Access) for the following:

I have a form called "CS_Order" from where I want to open a report called “Packing list”
On the form there is field call PO number (it is a text box). There are multiple records with different PO numbers. When I click on the text box I want to open a report that based record/field I clicked on. For example: I have two records. One with PO # 12345 and one with PO 23456. When clicking on this text box with the value 12345 the report that opens should contain all the values for that selected record. How do I translate this to VBA?

I just recently started to explore VBA so I do not have extensive knowledge on the subject.

This is what I came up with:

```
Private Sub PO_Click()
Dim strDocName As String
Dim strLinkCriteria As String

strDocName = "Packing_list"
strLinkCriteria = "[PO] = Forms![CS_Order]![PO]"

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

DoCmd.OpenReport strDocName, acViewPreview, , strLinkCriteria
End Sub
```

The result however is an empty report.

Comment: If your report is called "Packing list", then setting `StrDocName = "Packing_list"` won't work. You'd need to use `[Packing list]`

Comment: Good edits! Now we have a question that I think can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Access but I think this might work.

First assign the value of the PO textbox to a variable

```
Dim POBoxValue As String

'assign to variable
POBoxValue = Forms![CS_Order]![PO]
'print to immediate window
Debug.Print "POBoxValue: " & POBoxValue
```

Then use the variable to create the criteria

```
strLinkCriteria = "[PO] = " & "'" & POBoxValue & "'"
Debug.Print "strLinkCriteria: " & strLinkCriteria
```

Here's the whole thing.

```
Private Sub PO_Click()
    Dim strDocName As String
    Dim strLinkCriteria As String
    Dim POBoxValue As String

    'assign to variable
    POBoxValue = Forms![CS_Order]![PO]
    'print to immediate window
    Debug.Print "POBoxValue: " & POBoxValue

    strDocName = "Packing_list"

    'assign and check your strLinkCriteria
    strLinkCriteria = "[PO] = " & "'" & POBoxValue & "'"
    Debug.Print "strLinkCriteria: " & strLinkCriteria

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

    DoCmd.OpenReport strDocName, acViewPreview, , strLinkCriteria
End Sub
```

Use F8 to run the macro step-by-step. Watch the value of each variable as it changes in the Watch window. Or just use the Debug.Print to output the value. Hover over the variable to see its value. This allows you to check your macro yourself. You can verify the inputs before executing a command.

Happy coding. If the above doesn't work let me know.

Comment: The report opens but does not show the values of the selected record in the report. I also tried the remark put in by nwhaught but with the same result. Any thoughts? I have this working using a macro where I first refresh, do a gotocontrol and then open the report.

Comment: What was the debug value of the `strLinkCriteria`?

Comment: Not sure, what you mean but I ran the add watch and it tell me the values is <Out of context> and type is Empty.

Comment: Learn to debug. Press F8 repeatedly to run your macro line by line. Now if you've added `strLinkCriteria` to the Watch window it will show you the value of that variable line by line. Also the Immediate window will receive the output from Debug.Print which is still there after the macro is done.